# Start and stop a (commandline) program and get its outputs

Tags: php, windows, linux, command-line

Is it possible to start and stop a commandline program from php (on the same machine)?

And retrieve its ouput on the command line from within PHP?

The question is related to the following question I asked regarding VB:
[Cancelling background-worker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188228/vb-net-cancelling-background-worker)

It works in VB now and I would like to create the same functionality using PHP.

It should work in both Linux and Windows (it would be great if it also works on MAC, however this is not necessary).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see PHP documentation for [system](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) or [exec](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) command